# React state not updating after one time change through event handler

Tags: reactjs, ziggeo-sdk, ziggeo-api

I have a simple state to handle how much re-records a user can do,

```
const [retakes, setRetakes] = useState(0);
  const onRerecord = () => {
    console.log(retakes + 1, "rere");
    setRetakes(retakes + 1);
  };
```

The `onRerecord` fires every time the user ask for a re-record from `react-ziggeo`:rerecordings

```
<ZiggeoRecorder
          apiKey={process.env.ZIGGEO_API_TOKEN}
          video={videoToken}
          onProcessed={onProcessed}
          recordings={3}
          onRerecord={onRerecord}
        />
```

On first re-record the state updates just fine, however after that the state still the same, It just didn't change at all, You can see here how the `console.log`s for `1 "rere"` is the same everytime.

[image]

Comment: Nothing appears to be wrong here. It will be interesting to see the code for `ZiggeoRecorder` however.

Comment: @Regnidorhcs, This is pretty much the implementation for ziggeo, nothing other than `import { ZiggeoRecorder } from "react-ziggeo"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Comment: Did you add this part to your code? useEffect(() => {
        if (recorder) {
            // DO stuff here
            recorder.on("any_event", function (rec) { ... }, recorder);
            recorder.get("attribute_name");
        }
    }, [recorder]);

Comment: Just wanted to mention that the `recordings={3}` will limit everyone to 1 recording and up to 2 re-recordings following that (3 recordings in total). It should be all automatic, without any additional checks needed on your end. By using onRerecord you could be aware that it did happen and how many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this- update previous state.

```
const [retakes, setRetakes] = useState(0);
  const onRerecord = () => {
    console.log(retakes + 1, "rere");
    setRetakes(retakes => retakes + 1);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

`ZiggeoRecorder` appears to be caching the first reference of `onRerecord` and use the same instance afterwards.

And as your `onRerecord` closes-over `retakes` it always uses the same value on future invocations:

You can use functional variation of `useState` to work around this problem:

```
setRetakes(retakes => retakes + 1);
```